# How to add model name to the regression plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to plot the regression coefficient where I get a plot like this [image]

For example I would like to add the model name into the plot such as this on the top of the image

```
`PC2 ~ Index + Lane + Gen`
```

How to do that? I would like to add the model names to the respective plots

My code which I'm using

```
plot_list = list()
for (i in seq(length(bb))) {
  p = ggcoefstats(bb[[i]])
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

pdf("plots1.pdf",height = 10,width = 6)
for (i in seq(length(bb))) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

My data `bb` which is my model output

```
> bb
$`PC2 ~ Sex + Index + Lane`

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = mrna.pcs)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         SexM   IndexAR002   IndexAR003   IndexAR004   IndexAR005   IndexAR006   IndexAR007   IndexAR008   IndexAR009   IndexAR010  
     0.8055     -11.3695       2.6964      -7.9438      -1.7453     -10.5309     -10.7135      -9.8775       4.4912       0.7830      -4.8674  
 IndexAR011   IndexAR012   IndexAR013   IndexAR014   IndexAR015   IndexAR016   IndexAR018   IndexAR019   IndexAR020   IndexAR021   IndexAR022  
    -8.1402     -10.6590      -8.1678       1.0441      -0.4174       7.2952      12.9489      -7.4206      -6.6895     -10.6862       4.9863  
 IndexAR023   IndexAR025   IndexAR027        Lane2        Lane3        Lane4        Lane5        Lane6        Lane7        Lane8  
     1.5614     -15.7488      -1.5925      12.3677     -10.3617     -55.5894      25.6420      34.1251      42.4888      16.1013
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `text(x, y, labels)`?

Comment: i tried for single plot but in loop i'm not sure how to incorporate the same ..

Answer (score 0):

I was not previously familiar with this package your using to create this visual, which is not actually `ggplot2`. According to this page, there is a `title` parameter that you should use within the function: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/ggcoefstats.html

You might benefit by converting this to `ggplot2`, however. The first thing I thought when I saw your visual was "this needs `ggrepel`". That will automatically move your text labels around so that they do not overlap. Seeing those coefficient values would seem to be very important. AFAIK, `ggrepel` only works with `ggplot2` not other graphing libraries.

Comment: "You might benefit by converting this to ggplot2" you mean after plotting it?

Comment: Use ggplot2 instead of ggstatsplot. But it would require you to figure out how to do several things that this package is doing natively from the lm object.

Comment: yes thats why i directly went for ggstatplot ..i think simpler solution is to add them using Photoshop instead of grinding  again

Comment: You could but over time that’s a lot of extra work. If you’re going to do this a lot, converting to ggplot and then using the repel functions could save you a lot of time

Comment: okay will give it a try